# Foreach loop is showing error while storing multiple id's

Tags: laravel

I am creating a group and also storing users id's in it but its showing error in foreach loop i.e. `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`.

Here is my controller code :

```
public function createGroup(Request $request)
{
    $user_id = request('user_id');
    $member = request('member');

    $data = array(
        'name'=>$request->name,  
    );

    $group = Group::create($data);

    if($group->id)
    {  
        $resultarr = array();              
        foreach($member as $data){
            $resultarr[] = $data['id'];
        }

        $addmem = new GroupUser();
        $addmem->implode(',', $resultarr);
        $addmem->group_id = $group->id;
        $addmem->status = 0;
        $addmem->save();

        return $this->sendSuccessResponse([
            'message'=>ResponseMessage::statusResponses(ResponseMessage::_STATUS_GROUP_SUCCESS)
        ]);
    }
}
```

I am adding values like this,
[image]

Desired Output,
I just want that each member to store with different id's in table and group id will be same.

Please help me out

Comment: ` $member = request('member');` this should be array inorder to work so add laravel valdation

Comment: try to print your $member  and check whether it is array or string.

Comment: you asked the same question 2 days ago. Kamlesh below provided the right answer on how to get an array for your $member (the same i told you 2 days ago)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid that if check, it does absolute nothing.

```
if($group->id)
```

Secondly your input is clearly a string, explode it and you will have the expected results. Secondly don't save it to a temporary variable, create a new GroupUser immediately.

```
foreach(explode(',', $member) as $data){
    $addmem = new GroupUser();
    $addmem->user_id = $data;
    $addmem->group_id = $group->id;
    $addmem->status = 0;
    $addmem->save();
}
```

That implode line makes no sense at all, i assumed there is a user_id on the GroupUser relation.

Answer (score 0):

u need to send array from postman

like

```
Key       |  value

member[]  |   6
member[]  |   3
```

or

```php
$memberArray = explode(",", $member = request('member'))

if($group->id)
    {  
        $resultarr = array();              
        foreach($memberArray as $data){
            $resultarr[] = $data['id'];
        }

        $addmem = new GroupUser();
        $addmem->implode(',', $resultarr);
        $addmem->group_id = $group->id;
        $addmem->status = 0;
        $addmem->save();

        return $this->sendSuccessResponse([
            'message'=>ResponseMessage::statusResponses(ResponseMessage::_STATUS_GROUP_SUCCESS)
        ]);
    }
```